# WCF: Is using WsHttpBinding interoperable?

Tags: wcf, interop, wshttpbinding, wcf-interoperability

As the name states... right now I'm using BasicHttpBinding, but I'm wondering if I can switch to WSHttpBinding and still be interoperable with, for example, Java.

Comment: If your communication partner also supports the WS-* standards, SOAP 1.2 and all - yes.

Answer (score 4):

wsHttpBinding and the newer ws2007HttpBinding both implement WS-* standards. You may have to configure the details so that they interoperate with your specific clients.

Answer (score 3):

WSHttpBinding offers a lot of interoperable features but in the same time it by default uses message security with Windows authentication, service credentials negotiation over SPNego protocol and security context (WS-SecureConversation). Windows authentication and SPNego are not good candidates for interoperability and secure conversation doesn't have to be provided by older SOAP stacks.

So the answer is "it depends". You usually have to configure WSHttpBinding to be interoperable with Java. Moreover you don't have "full" control over used protocols (especially for security part) so sometimes you will use custom binding for interoperability.