# C# WCF Web Service on localhost consumed by Java Client

Tags: c#, java, wcf, wcf-interoperability

currently my WCF Service is using net.pipes to talk on local machine.
Now I want to consume the web service in java **on the same machine**.
Here I have some questions:

- Which binding I have to use to talk on local machine with Java client?

I don't want to go over network and the client must be able to consume the web service.

Do you may have any articles or tipps how to start here? May some hints what I have to take care about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[BasicHttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.basichttpbinding.aspx) exposes a SOAP 1.1 wsdl which is probably the most interoperable between JAVA and .NET. If your calls are local then you won't go out to the network.

**EDIT**

WsHttpBinding supports SOAP 1.2 which is a larger, more complex specification and therefore more open to interpretation by different vendors. So while it may work fine, it will generally be less interoperable.

Specifically there may be differences in the way security is handled on either side (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5277489/569662) for a good explanation).

Comment: will give it a test and accept it if it works. Thanks so far.